# In the Core Service in Web 8, what is the batch_netTcp_201501 binding used for?

Tags: core-service, web8

I am using the Core Service in SDL Web 8.1.1 and noticed a new binding in the sample config file "Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.dll.config" called 'batch_netTcp_201501'.

What is this binding used for?  I was unable to find any documentation about it in the SDL Live Docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is used by Batch processor to perform operations on multiple items. You can read more in CoreService API docs under `ICoreServiceBatch201501 Members`. Please let me know if you also need some code example and I will add it.